# Width option in vbar glyph is not adjusting automatically in bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

When there are too few values on x-axis, the vertical bars on the graph are not having the width specified, instead they are displayed as big blocks.

For Example:

```
    from bokeh.io import show, output_file
    from bokeh.plotting import figure
    output_file("bar_basic.html")
    fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
    counts = [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6]


    p = figure(x_range=fruits, plot_height=350, title="Fruit Counts",
       toolbar_location=None, tools="")
    p.vbar(x=fruits, top=counts, width=0.9)
    p.y_range.start = 0
    show(p)
```

This shows the graph, which contains the 6 vertical bars with the provided width.
[Image with many values on x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlGuE.png)

But, when we reduce the number of values in x-axis(only 2 fruits in this case), the 2 vertical bars are being displayed with bigger width.

```
    from bokeh.io import show, output_file
    from bokeh.plotting import figure
    output_file("bar_basic.html")
    fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears' ]
    counts = [5, 3]


    p = figure(x_range=fruits, plot_height=350, title="Fruit Counts",
       toolbar_location=None, tools="")
    p.vbar(x=fruits, top=counts, width=0.9)
    p.y_range.start = 0
    show(p)
```

Now the image would be:
[With two values on x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDqPX.png)

How can I able to display the width of the vertical bars always same irrespective of number of values in x-axis?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a Categorical axis (as in your examples) then the bar width is always a percentage of the "full category width", E.g. 0.9 always means "90% of the space a category takes up on the axis" which means if there are fewer categories, the bar will always be physically wider.

You can either:

- Manually adjust the widths, based on the number of categories, and your preferences/requirements, or
- Not use a categorical axis. I.e. if you use a standard "numeric" axis you can specify and actual width according to the axis. You would also have to "fake" categorical axis labels by using a tick formatter of some kind.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @bigreddot
I would like to go with the option 2.
I am not able to figure out this part of the second option

**Not use a categorical axis. I.e. if you use a standard "numeric" axis you can specify and actual width according to the axis.**

If you don't mind could you give the coding here.

I am able to figure out this bit.

**You would also have to "fake" categorical axis labels by using a tick formatter of some kind.**

by using:
`p.xaxis.ticker = [1, 2, 3 ]
p.xaxis.major_label_overrides = {1: 'Apples', 2: 'Pears', 3: 'Nectarines'}`

Comment: I only mean that e.g. if your x_range is (0,10) and you set a `width=5` then the bar will take up half the plot space. Or in other words, that hen you use a default numeric range/axis then the width number corresponds to distances on that scale.

Comment: I only have 10 categories at most, so now I have a condition to set the width based on number of categories.
    if length_entities < 2 :
        width = 0.1
    elif length_entities < 3:
        width = 0.2
    elif length_entities < 4:
        width = 0.3
....
....
I know it is too manual, but it is doing the job. Thanks again!